# With Spring-Boot 2.3.3 H2 In-Memory Database throws NonTransientConnectionException

Tags: spring-boot, h2

Currently I'm working on a Spring-Boot project and unfortunately run into an errror which I don't know how to solve...

I set up H2 In-Memory-Databae for my project in **application.properties** like this:

```
    # H2 In-Memory-Database Config
    spring.datasource.generate-unique-name=false
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;MODE=MYSQL
    spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

Calling the H2-Console on localhost:8080/h2-console and trying to log in, it throws me the following error:

> **Database "/Users/.../testdb" not found, either pre-create it or allow remote database creation (not recommended in secure environments) [90149-200] 90149/90149
> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientConnectionException: Database "/Users/supportmicha/testdb" not found, either pre-create it or allow remote database creation (not recommended in secure environments) [90149-200]**

Data is there and its getting populated on application start using this **data.sql** script:

```
    INSERT INTO my_table (id, name, style, created_date, last_modified_date, min_on_hand, quantity_to_produce, price, upc, version ) values ('0a818933-087d-47f2-ad83-2f986ed087eb', 'TestName_1', 'TestStyle_1', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , 12,  200, 12.95, '0631234200036', 1);
    INSERT INTO my_table (id, name, style, created_date, last_modified_date, min_on_hand, quantity_to_brew, price, upc, version ) values ('a712d914-61ea-4623-8bd0-32c0f6545bfd', 'TestName_2', 'TestStyle_2', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , 12,  200, 12.95, '0631234300019', 1);
    INSERT INTO my_table (id, beer_name, beer_style, created_date, last_modified_date, min_on_hand, quantity_to_produce, price, upc, version ) values ('026cc3c8-3a0c-4083-a05b-e908048c1b08', 'TestName_3', 'TestStyle_3', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , 12,  200, 12.95, '0083783375213', 1);
```

In another conversation here on stackoverflow somebody solved this problem by using an older Spring-Boot-Version (2.1.15) - but I'm on 2.3.3 now and it's very important to keep this version.

**Another mentioned that it can be solved by setting *generating unique name* to false - like this:**

```
    spring.datasource.generate-unique-name=false
```

But that didn't help.

I would be very happy, if someone could give a hint on what exactly is going wrong here and how to solve it.

Comment: Looks like you are connecting to the wrong DB. A file-based one instead of the memory-based one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call the H2 console and see the H2 login form, set the `JDBC URL:` form field value to `jdbc:h2:mem:testdb`.